# How to extend the battery life on my laptop when running Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, power-management, hp

I have a little problem. I bought a Pavilion G4 with Windows 7, but I really hate Windows, so I installed Ubuntu on it.

On Windows, the laptop's battery lasts longer than it does on Ubuntu. I've also noticed that the processor is constantly running, because on Windows the laptop's internal temperature is not as high as it is on Ubuntu.

I read something about wakeups and that some processes have 150 to 500 wakeups per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had great utility with powertop. It is available to be installed on ubuntu. One might need to be careful about what one is doing with it though. As powertop might recommend things which it thinks as a effective optimization but might cause a loss of feature like usb hangups etc.
To install powertop run

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

Then run

```
sudo powertop
```

and follow instructions to speed up the computer speed.

Answer (score 0):

Jupiter is a software for power control. It works by limiting the performance of your laptop.

introduction and downloading: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html